# How to count uppercase words in a string in Java?

Tags: java, count, cpu-word, uppercase

I need to count the total number of uppercase words in a string, but I just can't figure out how to do it without complex if statements and checks involved.

I've tried and written down something like this:

```
private int uppercaseWordsCount(String input){
    count = 0;
    String[] ss = input.split("\\s");
    for (String s: ss){
        //???
        }

    }

    return count;

}
```

And I still have no clue about a good condition to match my need. The thing is I have to deal with whole words (special characters like exclamation marks count as uppercase characters for the purpose of the method) and not single characters, as the rest of the system I'm writing already does.

Comment: What's wrong with writing multiple checks or complex if statements?

Comment: Break the problem down. What goes in the `???` part? Probably something like, "if this is an uppercase word, increment the counter." So write up that condition, substituting "is this an uppercase word?" with a method that returns boolean. Now you need to implement that method but it's a simpler problem to solve.

Comment: @Brian As long as there are simpler solutions, I'd rather stick to them, Occam's razor for the win!

Anyway, I've managed to find a satisfying answer, thank you for the interest!

Comment: This may sound harsh, and I apologize if it does, that's not the intent... but if this problem is something you need help with, then you might actually benefit from a bit of practice doing things the "hard" way (ie, not relying on the person who wrote the regex parser having solved the problem for you, etc).

Comment: @yshavit True, I'm not saying I don't need practice, I would be stupid to say something like that, but I was being stuck on this problem (a simple one, must admit) for hours, as the last time I've written something in Java was two years ago and I remember almost nothing. I need to acquire the programmer mentality again, and stack overflow could help me reach that target, that's why in the first place I've posted such a question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could split each string via the [`split()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) call as you are currently doing to obtain each word. At this point, you have options with how you want to handle comparing each of the words to determine if they are uppercase.

**Compare Your String to an Uppercase Version**

You could also compare the string to its uppercase equivalent as well using the [`toUpperCase()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toUpperCase()) method and increment accordingly

```
// The string is the same as an upper-cased version of itself
if(s.equals(s.toUpperCase())){
     // Then increment your count
     count++;
}
```

**Check The String Against A Regular Expression**

You could also use a regular expression to see if all of the characters within the string are uppercase via the [`matches()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches(java.lang.String)) method :

```
// Increment your count if the string consists of only uppercase characters
if(s.matches("^[A-Z]+$")){
     count++;
}
```

Comment: Was it that simple? Thank you very much! As you can see I've piled up some rust as I haven't written anything in Java for a couple of years. :D

Comment: `s == s.toUpperCase()` should probably be `s.equals(s.toUpperCase())` The implementation in JDK 7 does happen to return `this` in the case that the string is already upper case; but that behavior isn't specified in the method contract, so I personally wouldn't want to rely on it. (Especially since `String#equals` fast-tracks to return true if the two instances are the same, anyway.)

Comment: Great point. It's been a long time since I've had to write any Java, I'll update it accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

This is how to do it using java 8

```
public static long countUpperCaseWord(String input) {
  // your object must be not null
  Objects.requireNonNull(input);

  // new stream of the array returned by the split call on input string
  return Stream.of(input.split("\\s")) 
               // we create a second stream that match the predicate passed throw the method filter
               .filter(word -> word.equals(word.toUpperCase())) 
               // finally we want to count how many words match this predicate
               .count();
}
```

And if need to count letter in uppercase in the entry :

```
  public static long countUpperCase(String input) {

     return input.chars()
                 .map(i -> (char) i)
                 .filter(c -> Character.isUpperCase(c))
                 .count();
  }
```

And if you want to improve this using more generics code you could write it like this :

```
 public static long countWordsUsingPredicate(String input, Predicate<String> predicate) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(input);

    return Stream.of(input.split("\\s")) 
                 .filter(predicate) 
                 .count();
}
```

And calling this util method by passing your predicate as a lambda expression to the method :

```
countUpperCaseWord("THIS BREAK", word -> word.equals(word.toUpperCase()))
```

Comment: Try the first method in my edit, sorry the second method is to count letter in uppercase in the entry

Comment: I'm not used to Java 8, could you please comment those methods you have written? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The simple way is to define your "upper case word pattern" and then count matches against it:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\b[A-Z\!\@\$\%\^\&\*\(\)\[\]]\S+\b");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("Your Input String Here");
int count = 0;
while (matcher.find()) { count++; }
System.out.printf("%d uppercase words.%n", count);
```